# oracle - script de select con detalle de todas las tablas

Tags: oracle, select

Estoy desarrollando una consulta a 3 tablas las cuales contiene los campos nombre y código y quisiera hacer un select de estas trayendo los datos de la siguiente manera:

- Tabla1Codigo
- Tabla1Codigo.Tabla2Codigo
- Tabla1Codigo.Tabla2Codigo.Tabla3Codigo
- Tabla1Codigo.Tabla2Codigo.Tabla3Codigo

Alguien me puede dar una pauta sobre la sentencia correcta que debería usar para crear el select.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Giovanni, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo del todo cómo quieres mostrar el resultado, pero la siguiente SQL simple te devuelve los datos.

```
SELECT nombre, codigo FROM Tabla1, Tabla2, Tabla3
```